# "Inputted" or "input"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, past-participles

I have used the word *inputted* in an assignment and am being forced to change it to *input*. However, both the Oxford English Dictionary (I am in New Zealand so this is most relevant) and MS Word list *inputted* as acceptable. Do others regard *inputted* as acceptable?

> The scope of this project will be clearly defined in that it is to strictly provide positive movie recommendations to users who have **inputted** a sufficient amount of data.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

"Inputted" may be acceptable per Oxford, but it sets my teeth on edge; my ear wants "input" to follow the same rules as "put".  I suspect I'm not the only one, which is probably why you're being forced to change it.

EDIT:  This question/answer has been getting a bit of attention recently, so I'd like to clarify my comment below.  There is a verb, **[putt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/putt?s=t)**, meaning "try to hit a golf ball into a hole by striking it gently so that it rolls across the green", which is often confused with **[put](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/put?s=t)** "to move or place".  (The confusion is natural, since the golfing term comes from a Scots variant of "put" - but the two words are distinct, and pronounced differently.)

The past tense of *put* is **put**; the past tense of *putt* is **putted**.  Since *input* is formed from "put" rather than "putt", it seems logical that its past tense should be **input**, rather than "inputted"; "inputted" sounds like a demented golfing term.

Comment: @MTH Hang on!!! - isn't inputted basically the past tense?  **"My jobs is to input data. Yesterday, I inputted 100 items."**  If you say "Yesterday I input 100 items" that sounds totally weird ....... doesn't it?!  Maybe my ear is going??  Help!

Comment: @Joe Blow - I guess it depends on your ear... As I said, *my* ear wants "input" to follow the same rules as "put"; if I "putted" 100 items yesterday, they had better have been golf balls.

Comment: @MTH So you would say "Yesterday I put 100 balls in a bag."  I suppose you're right, thanks.  That's the damn trouble with these new, computer-and-technology-related words - there's no rich backdrop feel.  I've got a feeling there's some situations where you would need to use "inputted" - but I can't put my finger on it :-/

Comment: @Joe Blow - Don't get me wrong - OED, NOAD and OALD all accept "inputted", and I'm not saying that my ear outweighs their judgment.  I'm just saying it sounds ugly, and if you have a choice between two correct words, why would you choose the ugly one?

Comment: Input has nothing to do with computer and technology.

Comment: As others have stated, the rules seem to allow it, and 'inputted' sounds pretty normal to me. I certainly use the word inputted in my daily speech in the same way it was used in the question ("Are you sure she inputted our correct information?"). The only way to use 'input' in the question that sounds right to me would be to force the present tense and say "to users who input a sufficient amount of data". Trying to say "to users who have input a sufficient amount of data" doesn't seem _wrong_, but it does sound weird to me.

Comment: @Patrick - Obviously you don't _have_ to justify it on grammatical grounds, but... could you?  "Input" is derived from "put", and "putted" is absolutely NOT correct unless you're talking about golf - so it comes down to "my ear prefers this and not that".

Comment: @MT_Head If we switched "input" for "put in", which I think works most of the time, it's obvious "putted in" doesn't work, and you could use that to discredit "inputted". I searched around and the best explanation I can offer for our discrepancy is the syllable stress. When I say "input" as "in put" (stressing both syllables), I agree with you ("in putted" is bad). When I only stress the "in", "inputted" seems better. "Input" also reminds me of "wet" and "rid": "He wet/wetted the bed", "We rid/ridded the town of rats". [Ngram of inputted,ridded,wetted](http://bit.ly/1uyK5de).

Comment: What's wrong with just saying "entered" data?

Comment: -1... your preference dictates neither correctness, nor objective ugliness, nor common usage. You're totally free, that is, to personally consider 'inputted' the better-sounding or even the correct choice, but it's also totally unreasonable to try and frame it as a matter of 'logic'; language is chock-full on principle of irregularities, and chiefly illogical ones to boot. 'Inputted' could easily be yet another.

Comment: @M.I.Wright - Although I did comment on objective ugliness, I said nothing about correctness (or, rather, I conceded that both are correct.)  I didn't even mention common usage - although a quick squint at an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=input%2C+inputted) seems to indicate that "inputted" is actually vanishingly _un_ common.  So... what exactly was your point?  "Yadda yadda English is totally illogical, so why bother yadda yadda" - did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 5):

My NOAD lists *input* and *inputted* both as acceptable participles. Same goes for the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/input_2).

Answer (score -6):

I just put this into one of my java programs.. and it seems to fit well since they have already input the data.

// Shows user how many of each currency unit is in the amount they inputted

Comment: don't you mean they have already "inputted" the data?

Comment: You can’t have “putted” anything in, you know.  There is no such word as *putted*, except insofar as concerns the game of golf. How currency came to be involved with putting, let alone how Java enters the picture, I have no idea, considering that I believe Sumatra fairly well dominates the sport.

Comment: -1 for being inconsistent in your comment and your explanation of it.

Comment: just use typed in

Comment: -1 - Worst.reasoning.ever.