# Past tense of 'to output': output or outputted?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, past-tense, conjugation, inflectional-morphology

According to Wikipedia, the past tense (and past participle) of the verb *to output* is either *output* or *outputted*. Are these two forms entirely interchangeable? Or do they have certain nuance in meaning or context (e.g. in programming one of the forms is preferred)?

> Instead of correct results, my program output/outputted garbage.

Which one should I choose? My logical sense tells me *output* is better because it derives from *put*, but intuitively I tend to use *outputted* when I speak and don't have time to think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inputted or input?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30684/inputted-or-input)

Comment: Wait.  Isn't **outputting** something you do in golf?

Comment: I've always used 'output' myself.

Comment: Instead of correct results, my program produced garbage.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/output) endorses both *output* and *outputted*.  [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+output%2Cwas+outputted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20output%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20outputted%3B%2Cc0) and a Google search (238K vs. 22K) yields evidence of a definite preference for *output*.  (Note: *is output* instead of *was output* yields similar results)

[image]

Comment: The question asks for the *past tense* of "output," instead of the *past participle*. The latter is used in passive voice.

Comment: @L.F. yes, but if the result does not match then this would be the only verb in existence to have *-ed* in past tense with no ending for past participle...

Answer (score -7):

The word "output" is a noun, not a verb. I believe "outputting" is just an illiterate form of "to put out" or "to produce as output".

Comment: Please name a general-purpose English language dictionary that does not include an entry for *output* as a verb.

Comment: This answer is as smug as it is wrong
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/output_2
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/output

Comment: @toniedzwiedz Both links now just go to company front pages.