# What to call a date field that represents when another date field was entered?

Tags: word-choice

I have a date field named "Initial Forecast Date" and I need another date field that represents when the user entered "Initial Forecast Date". What would be the most appropriate name for this field?

I've come up with a few:

- Initial Forecast Date Timestamp (except I only want to show the date, no time)
- Initial Forecast Date-stamp
- Initial Forecast Date Set Date
- Initial Forecast Set Date

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming things (especially programming things) is explicitly off-topic, according to the [help].

Comment: I apologize, you are correct.

Comment: (Though I certainly do sympathize with your plight!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow would be the best place to ask this, as you can get a more relevant answer from a UI expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some field is usually "modified" from its initial state, you can use

- ***Modified Forecast Date***

Otherwise, I propose:

- ***Inputted Forecast Date*** (you will probably cringe, but [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/input#) (see verb form) has an entry. Use it at your own risk. See related [EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30684/inputted-or-input))
- ***Entered Forecast Date*** (signifies the user has entered the date)
- ***Forecast Date Set*** sounds good as well

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with "Initial Forecast Date Set/Entered On". Now I'm debating between "Set" or Entered".